# Use yii2 built in validators

Tags: javascript, validation, yii2

I'm looking for a way to use yii2s built-in javascript email validator, when I use a form, I can see that `yii.validation.email` is available, but looking at the source in `/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/assets/yii.validation.js` I can't figure out how to use it to validate a text string to see if it is valid.

Comment: What is the use case ?

Comment: I want to validate some string to see if it is valid

Comment: Well, it is obvious :-) but why not using activeform validation ?

Comment: because it's not part of my model, so I can't use active inputs.can I make a model property and have a rule on that?

Comment: Yes you can. You could also create a form model to handle your model and other inputs.

Comment: that was one way to do it but I want to use that validating myself and not relying on yii to set it up! if that makes any sense :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I was looking for but

I didn't realize that I can create a public property in my model, and have a rule for that in rules like

```
public $quick_insert;

public function rules()
{
    return [
      ...
     ['quick_insert', 'email'],
```